# React unique "key" error

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I'm going through a tutorial for todo list in React and ran into the following error, I have spent quite a time and just can't find the mistake..here is the error and the code for the component and this is the code for the course repo(problem appears on this commit):

https://github.com/andrewjmead/react-course-todo-app/commit/0521f151705f78cb9f8d69262eb093f1431cb9ca

Any help much appreciated.

Warning: Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop. Check the render method of `TodoList`. See fb.me/react-warning-keys for more information.

Also there is an error in terminal, for the spread operator in case TOGGLE_TODO

```
return {
...todo, // here
completed: nextCompleted,
completedAt: nextCompleted ? moment().unix() : undefined
};

var React = require('react');
var { connect } = require('react-redux');
import Todo from 'Todo';
var TodoAPI = require('TodoAPI');

export var TodoList = React.createClass ({
    render: function() {
        var { todos, showCompleted, searchText } = this.props;
        var renderTodos = () => {
            if(todos.length === 0) {
                return (
                    <p className="container__message">No tasks</p>
                );
            }
            return TodoAPI.filterTodos(todos, showCompleted, searchText).map((todo) => {
                return (
                    //add unique key prop to keep track of individual components
                    <Todo key={todo.id} {...todo} />
                );
            });
        };
        return (
            <div>
                {renderTodos()}
            </div>
        );  
    }
});

export default connect(
    (state) => {
        return state;
    }
)(TodoList);
```

Reducers:

```
var uuid = require('uuid');
var moment = require('moment');

export var searchTextReducer = (state = '', action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'SET_SEARCH_TEXT':
            return action.searchText;
        default: 
            return state;
    };
};

export var showCompletedReducer = (state = false, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'TOGGLE_SHOW_COMPLETED':
            return !state;
        default: 
            return state;
    };    
};

export var todosReducer = (state = [], action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
        case 'ADD_TODO':
            return [
                ...state,
                {
                    text: action.text,
                    id: uuid(),
                    completed: false,
                    createdAt: moment().unix(),
                    completedAt: undefined                   
                }
            ];
        case 'TOGGLE_TODO':
            return state.map((todo) => {
                if(todo.id === action.id) {
                    var nextCompleted = !todo.completed;

                    return {
                        ...todo,
                        completed: nextCompleted,
                        completedAt: nextCompleted ? moment().unix() : undefined
                    };
                } else {
                    return todo;
                }
            });
        case 'ADD_TODOS':
            return [
                ...state,
                ...action.todos
            ];
        default: 
            return state;
    }
};


Webpack:

var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  entry: [
    'script!jquery/dist/jquery.min.js',
    'script!foundation-sites/dist/js/foundation.min.js',
    './app/app.jsx'
  ],
  externals: {
      jquery: 'jQuery'
  },
  plugins: [
      new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
          '$': 'jquery',
          'jQuery': 'jquery'
      })
  ],
  output: {
    path: __dirname,
    filename: './public/bundle.js'
  },
  resolve: {
    root: __dirname,
    modulesDirectories: [
        'node_modules',
        './app/components',
        './app/api'
    ],
    alias: {
        applicationStyles: 'app/styles/app.scss',
        actions: 'app/actions/actions.jsx',
        reducers: 'app/reducers/reducers.jsx',
        configureStore: 'app/store/configureStore.jsx'
    },
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        query: {
          presets: ['react', 'es2015']
        },
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/
      }
    ]
  },
  devtool: 'cheap-module-eval-source-map'
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

node-uuid is deprecated, check here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid

You can update your package.json by installing uuid and see if it helps:

npm install uuid

Just don't forget to update var uuid = require('node-uuid'); to var uuid = require('uuid'); in your other files.

P.S. Do you get any errors in your terminal when you run a webpack?

Comment: can you share your reducers/actions file?

Comment: it seems that you are missing babel stage-0 in your webpack if you get the spread operator error, try installing npm install --save-dev babel-preset-stage-0

Answer (score 4):

In React, when you are rendering multiple equal components (in your case, the todos) you need to add a unique key to each one of them, that's because React needs to know how they are going to be treated in the virtual dom.

You can do various things to fix this:

1. In the for loop, create an index variable and increment it by 1 each time a loop finishes, then set that as the key for each rendered component.
2. If you're fetching your todos from an api, set an id to each todo and use it as your component key.
3. Use a random number generator to set a unique key on each of your todos.

The best approaches are the #2 and #3, I see that in your case you're trying to do the #2 (setting the key by todo id) but I think it's undefined, check it.

Another solution is to use a [uuid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) on each rendered component/todo.

To do that, you can install [node-uuid](https://github.com/kelektiv/node-uuid).

Run: `npm i --save node-uuid`

Then do the import in your file: `import uuid from 'node-uuid'` or `const uuid = require('node-uuid')`

Now change your code to be like this:

```
return TodoAPI.filterTodos(todos, showCompleted, searchText).map((todo) => {
  return (
    //add unique key prop to keep track of individual components
    <Todo key={uuid()} {...todo} />
  );
});
```

And then you're good to go.

Comment: Yeah I got it in parent component(TodoApp), I've tried your solution but I still get the same error message.. My code is up to date with the instructor's, even when I clone his code and fiddle around I get the error. So it's the identical code, up to this commit: https://github.com/andrewjmead/react-course-todo-app/commit/0521f151705f78cb9f8d69262eb093f1431cb9ca

Comment: Won't `uuid()` return a new unique identifier each time the component renders? At that point you might as well just using Math.random() to generate your keys. This seems terrible for performance. Ideally, you would use a database identifier returned in the API call, but as a fallback, you could do `todo.title + index`. This method should generate the same keys as long as the order of the todo items doesn't change, but it will also ensure that two items with the same title won't generate the same key.

Answer (score 2):

I bet `todo.id` is `undefined` and therefore not unique.  Can you include `todos` in your example?

Comment: Please check the answer on bntzio's post the whole code is included on the link

Answer (score 2):

You can add `index` param to your `map` function, then pass that index to your `Todo` component:

```
export var TodoList = React.createClass ({
    render: function() {
        var { todos, showCompleted, searchText } = this.props;
        var renderTodos = () => {
            if(todos.length === 0) {
                return (
                    <p className="container__message">No tasks</p>
                );
            }
            return TodoAPI.filterTodos(todos, showCompleted, searchText).map((todo, index) => {    // here <====
                return (
                    //add unique key prop to keep track of individual components
                    <Todo key={`key-${index}`} {...todo} />
                );
            });
        };
        return (
            <div>
                {renderTodos()}
            </div>
        );  
    }
});
```

Comment: Be careful with this approach; it can cause problems if you ever re-render the parent with different `todos` since the keys will be reused

Comment: Ok I'll keep in mind that.
Just one question: if the children changes how the reuse of the keys could cause a problem? because the old children will be removed and their keys with them (well I think that is how it happens)

Comment: thanks I have tried that before already but I still got the same error...