# Warning: Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop. Check the render method of `Units`

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

This is only my second question here, so sorry if it's in the wrong place or has the wrong tags or anything.

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { getUnits } from '../reducers/units';
import { Menu, Container, Grid, Header, Form } from 'semantic-ui-react';

class Units extends React.Component {

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    const { dispatch, course } = this.props
    if (prevProps.course.id !== course.id)
      dispatch(getUnits(course.id))
  }

  units = () => {
    return this.props.units.map( unit => 
      <ul>
        <li key={unit.id}> {unit.name}</li>
        <button>Edit Module Name</button> 
        <button>Delete Module</button> 
      </ul> 
    )
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Container>
        <Header as="h3" textAlign="center">Modules</Header>
        { this.units() }
      </Container>
    )
  }
}
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return { units: state.units, course: state.course }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Units);
```

I'm getting the error in the title of this question even though I have keys in the li elements and they are unique. I can see that they're different in the redux dev tools state, but for some reason I still get that error. I have looked at other similar errors here on stackoverflow but none of those seemed to solve this specific problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React unique "key" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43621629/react-unique-key-error)

Answer (score 7):

The answer [@NorianNyx](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3590812/noriannyx) is good, basically you need to add an unique key to each component. However adding a index is not a good practice as this will not represent the item every single time. If you delete or add a new item to the list the index will change.

From [React](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html):

> The best way to pick a key is to use a string that uniquely identifies a list item among its siblings. Most often you would use IDs from your data as keys

So the updated solution to this will be:

```
return this.props.units.map((unit) => (
<ul key={unit.id}>
    <li> {unit.name}</li>
    <button>Edit Module Name</button> 
    <button>Delete Module</button> 
</ul>

));
```

In this way your item always will have an unique id

Answer (score 3):

Your `<ul>` component needs a `key` prop.

Just change it to:

```
 return this.props.units.map((unit, i) => (
    <ul key={i}>
        <li> {unit.name}</li>
        <button>Edit Module Name</button> 
        <button>Delete Module</button> 
    </ul>
 ));
```

Comment: Becasue, as @Tholle mentioned, all top level components of an array need a key for React internal stuff. More info can be found: https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html

Comment: You may also get warnings from React against using an iterator as a key. In that case, just prepend it as a string, like `'module-' + i` or similar.